# JSON Conversion to DataSet

Tags: c#, json, datatable, dataset

I have a JSON string with Multiple JSON Object. I would like to know how to deserialize Json string to DataSet.

I have deserialize JSON string to DataTable. It works fine but I would like to know how to convert multiple JSON object to dataset

Below is sample JSON:

```
{
"Name": "Jamal",
"Age": "42",
"City": "Mumbai",
"EducationalInfo": [{
    "Degree": "BE",
    "University": "Cristian Universiy"
}, {
    "Degree": "ME",
    "University": "Texas University"
}],
"LoanInfo": [{
    "LoanType": "Car Loan",
    "Amount": "1000000"
}, {
    "LoanType": "Personal",
    "Amount": "200000"
}]
}
```

Expected Output is:

Name, Age, City is one datatable

Degree & University is one datatable

LoanType & Amount is one datatable

Please suggest how to covert this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to convert personal fields to Array, before deserializing to DataSet

```
     using Newtonsoft.Json;

    var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);

    var propsToRemove = jObj.Properties()
                            .Where(p => p.Value.Type != JTokenType.Array)
                            .ToArray();

    jObj["PersonalInfo"] = new JArray(new JObject(propsToRemove));

    for (var i = 0; i < propsToRemove.Count(); i++)
        propsToRemove[i].Remove();
        
    DataSet ds = jObj.ToObject<DataSet>();
```

test

```
var tableNames = string.Join(", ", ds.Tables.OfType<DataTable>()
                       .Select(dt =>dt.TableName ));
```

test result

```
EducationalInfo, LoanInfo, PersonalInfo
```

Answer (score -1):

To convert the given JSON string into a `DataSet` with multiple `DataTables`, you can utilize the `Newtonsoft.Json` library in C#.
Use below class to deserialize the JSON string.

```
Rootobject rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonString);

public class Rootobject
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Age { get; set; }
  public string City { get; set; }
  public Educationalinfo[] EducationalInfo { get; set; }
  public Loaninfo[] LoanInfo { get; set; }
}
    
public class Educationalinfo
{
  public string Degree { get; set; }
  public string University { get; set; }
}
    
public class Loaninfo
{
  public string LoanType { get; set; }
  public string Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nilesh, JSON filed everything comes dynamically, so we couldn't not create class object for this.

Comment: Why are you posting an answer for the sake of posting it? The model you created uses the variable type `string` for fields that include numbers....